# How to use USB Key in Xen 5.6 Environment?

Tags: windows-server-2003, xenserver, usb-flash-drive

I am looking for a way to use USB key on a guest OS running on a 5.6 Xen Server environment. The catch is that I need to actually detect in the Guest OS (Win2003 Server) like an actual USB Key. Attaching it as a storage drive doesnt work (It is a key with special attributes that servers as a licensing mechanism).

Just wondering if anyone has had a similar need and found a good solution?

Thanks,

Nate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally I just go with USB over IP solutions for this, like [Anywhere USB](http://www.digi.com/products/usb/anywhereusb.jsp), easy and usually works great.

The really good solutions like the one linked above can even share the end-point device over multiple guests (on a USB port to port basis) so it can actually be quite cost effective in some situations.

Answer (score 0):

We used the network usb hub for a couple of VM scenarios. We also found that you can map the USB controller from the physical machine directly to the operating system (windows server 2003 in our cases). This requires figuring out exactly which hub controller is using what usb ports but it was a great workaround for software using a USB HASP key.